# jquery-ui draggable doesn't work inside an ajax block

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery

I can't seem to change the _drag option within an ajax block inside the drop block. Used jQuery 1.6 and 1.7 with jQuery ui 1.8.6 and 1.8.16.

```
$('div.equippment').droppable({
  accept: 'div.my_wep, div.store_wep',
  tolerance: 'intersect',
  drop: function(e, ui) {
    var _drop = $(this), _drag = ui.draggable, _class = _drag.attr('class'), _swapsell = false, _dragid = _drag.find('img').attr('name');
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'json',
      url: _url,
      data: ({to_inv: _from_store, slot: _drop.attr('id').replace('slot_','')}),
      success: function(data) {
        _drag.draggable("option","revert",true); // Doesn't work yay
      }
    });
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting any errors? Looks like you need to close the success function.

Comment: Fixed a copy-and-paste mistake. Did not close the "}" on the success block initially when I should have. Thanks :)